# One to many CakePHP3 (via matching table)

Tags: mysql, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I was wondering, if it is possible to create a OneToMany Relationship in CakePHP3 **via a matching Table** in the DB.
This is what my DB looks like:
[Showcase of DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7dDF.png)

This is my Table for ItemA:

```
    $this->belongsTo('ItemB', [
        'foreignKey' => 'item_a_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'item_b_id',
        'joinTable' => 'item_a_item_b'
    ]);
```

This is my Table for ItemB:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('ItemA', [
        'foreignKey' => 'item_b_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'item_a_id',
        'joinTable' => 'item_a_item_b'
    ]);
```

However, when I create a Control for ItemA in the template, it still gives me a Multiple Select.

```
echo $this->Form->control('item_b._ids', ['options' => $item_b, 'empty' => true]);
```

When I change this Form to Single Select, the selected Object will not be passed. I'm stuck to a Multiple Select :(

Is this the correct implementation of the DB Schema in Cake? Do I have to use the 'through' option? I'm confused...

Edit#1: It works if I configure ItemA with belongsToMany rather than belongsTo. But that would be a ManyToMany Relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, this isn't how you'd structure a one-to-many relationship. To enforce this at the DB level you would simply add `tbl_item_a.id` to the `tbl_item_b` table like:

`tbl_item_b.item_a_id`

However, by the sounds of it you know that already. And personally I don't see anything wrong with the setup as you have it, so long as it's documented (for others in the future).

By the sounds of it. The problem you're having isn't with the DB though, it's with the client-side rendering. For which you will want to use the [select](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_select) `FormHelper` function:

`echo $this->Form->select(/*field name*/, /*[options]*/)`

Comment: I know that it should be designed without a matching table.

However, there is something wrong with the configuration rather than the Template, because I don't seee any information concerning ItemB in ItemA when it gets saved

Comment: What do you table and entity objects look like? I ask because you may need to "tell cake" that it's a many to many relationship and limit input by virtue of controlling the client side output.

Comment: I've created them via bake. I changed nothing in Entity, in Table, I added the relations, as seen above.

Comment: I've changed both tables to belongsToMany and added $rules->validCount('itemB', 1, '<='); in ItemA Table. With this, it's not possible to select more than one option. 

Adding option 'type'=>'select', 'multiple'=>false to $this->Form->control  in the template leads to the problem, that the data is not saved correctly. It seems that there is no ItemB entity object in the request data.